# Bluetooth audio suddenly mono

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 (upgraded from 18.04, if that's relevant) and suddenly my Bluetooth headphones (Sennheiser HD 4.50BT) only have sound on the left channel. The headsets work fine when connected via Bluetooth to my smartphone and the voice-confirmations of commands reproduce in both channels, as well as audio connected via 3.5mm headphone jack, so problem eems to stems from my laptop's Bluetooth.

Audio was working fine until last reboot. Not sure if any kind of update was installed prior to power-down or something like that. I've tried rebooting both the headphones and the computer, and totally removing the Bluetooth device and re-pairing on configs.

My laptop's a "Banghõ" (generic Intel i5 Ivybridge laptop), I'm not sure what information is relevant to troubleshooting this (or the commands for getting information). If anyone can give me a hand, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have speakers on the PC? If you have not already, check it's not just the basic sound settings. Go to Ubuntu settings (Sound) section. Check the `Balance`. Click on the `Test` button and check the left/right channels there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into sound settings and check that the left/right balance is in the middle, and not completely on one side of the spectrum (in GNOME this is in `System Settings`>`Sound`>`Balance`).

Comment: I can't believe that was actually it, thank you! It seems that if you use the scroll wheel on that settings page you can very easily mess that up without realizing (and also change the output device by mistake).